# What is the lifecycle of an ASP.NET connection to HAProxy?

Tags: asp.net, connection-pooling, haproxy

I've been running experiments with HAProxy's reconfiguration and am seeing some results I don't fully understand.

I'm running HAProxy on CentOS and am sending it requests from Windows 7. For the reconfiguration, I'm using "haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -sf $(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid)".

I ran two experiments:

1) A console application in Windows is running in a loop, spawning a new webclient each iteration, and sending a request to HAProxy. While the loop is running, I do a hot reconfig. --> this results in the reconfig being blocked until the console application is closed (bad).

2) A console application in Windows is running in a loop, sending a request to an ASP.NET website. The ASP.NET website on each page load sends a request to HAProxy. While the loop is running, I do a hot reconfig. --> this results in the reconfig swapping almost immediately (good).

I think that ASP.NET connection pooling is to blame in the connection staying open in the first experiment, but I was wondering if someone could explain to me exactly what's happening.

Comment: Are you Disposing your web clients after each use?

Comment: @Rand Davis Please provide more information to assist in diagnosing -- what is the exact command you are using for `hot reload`?  Are you using the built-in system service management?  If not, why?  Are your `console application`'s multi-threaded?  Are you downloading a large file in #1? What does your full HAProxy config look like? (pasting it as code at the bottom of your question would be oh-so helpful :)